# How to compare a String to two values in a single if

Tags: java, if-statement

That is the method I've tried. If they type *Yes* with caps and *yes* without it will still count and it does not work.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String In = in.next();
if (In.equals("Yes") & (In.equals("yes")) { 
    // Do this
}
else {
    // Do this
}
```

Comment: you probably want to start your variable names with lowercase because of convention.

Comment: Just a small piece of advice: when comparing a variable with a string, you should probably use the idiom `"yes".equals(variable)` instead of `variable.equals("yes")`, to avoid a `NullPointerException` if the variable holds `null`

Comment: i cant seem to type In.equalsIgnoreCase("")

Comment: What does that mean you can't type it?

Comment: it does not let me do it

Comment: sais its undefined for Scanner type or something

Comment: Capital 'I'... this is where bad variable naming conventions create issues ;)

Comment: by ide do you mean a program which i use to do this in if so then eclispe

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase` is a `String` method. Write it to a String variable to use it. It has nothing to do with `Scanner`, hence the error.

Comment: capital i is not the problem

Comment: Change `String In` to `String inputValue` or something and it will make things a lot clearer :-)

Comment: ok i may just be dumb but i typed String equals....

Comment: and it still sais scanner is undefined for string type Scanner

Comment: IM A GIVEN i typed my input string wrong ffs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do what you're talking about.  This is the syntax:

```
if (In.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    //Do something
}
```

It is also possible to do this:

```
if (In.equals("YES") || In.equals("yes")) {
    //Do something
}
```

However, there's no reason to with the String method's case-insensitive comparison, see above.  You really don't want to use your current syntax for 3 reasons: (1) AND operator is &&.  Your operator is bitwise AND but this is not a bitwise operation.  (2) It's not possible to have a string be equal to more than one thing, so use OR not AND if you're going that way.  (3) Watch your parentheses, they're off.

Comment: Thank you so much i am going text it out ty

Comment: and can i type for example if i want them to type Acc/accounts

Comment: please write your question more clearly, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: i type if (In.equalsIgnoreCase("acc") || In.equalsIgnoreCase("accounts"){?

Comment: yes with one more parenthesis at the end of your conditional

Comment: ya i just ment if that statement was correct TY so much and have a great day :)

Comment: np, please upvote/accept if this was helpful

Comment: need 15 rep told you im new XD

Comment: Your point `1` is wrong: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=65. There is a difference between a single `&` in an if statement and an single `&` "somewhere" else.

Comment: @Dan It wasn't for you, it was for La-comadreja.

Comment: i know but how do i type the In.equalsIgnoreCase("")